# Viterbi decoder for meteor M2 and similar satellites

Tags: python, viterbi

I am working on decoding QPSK from Meteor M2 satellites and BPSK from Cubesats (like Funcube). I have reached to a point where I am able to get the constellation and get the soft bits (A [blog](https://aerospaceresearch.net/?p=825) about the progress) from RTLSDR IQ recordings.

To further decode the information, I would need to use a Viterbi decoder. The inputs being the soft bits. I was wondering if there was some open source code (in python) that I could perhaps use to do this?

So far, the resources I found were application specific and not in python. So, I would also appreciate if anyone could point me towards some tutorials/implementations etc. that could help me implement one.

Any sort of input would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much for your time!

If you are interested you can find the project [here](https://github.com/aerospaceresearch/DirectDemod).